# -W flag for gcc to detect taking const pointer of uninitialised variable

Tags: c, gcc-warning

I have the following code, saved on [Coding Ground here](http://goo.gl/hJyuxE):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int const *x)
{
    printf("Hello, %d!\n", *x);
}

int main()
{
    int y;

    foo(&y);
    y = 3;
    printf("Hello, World %d!\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wuninitialized -o main *.c
```

However, I get no warning about taking a const pointer of an uninitialised variable, and I [cannot find a suitable flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Note: pasting the code into [Gimpel's Online Lint](http://www.gimpel-online.com/OnlineTesting.html) gives me the expected:

> test.c  12  Warning 603:  Symbol 'y' (line 10) not initialized

Comment: Why do you think there is a flag for this? You better try static analysis tools or runtime analyzers or sanitizers for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> -Wuninitialized
>   Warn whenever an automatic variable is used without first being initialized.
>
> These warnings are possible only in optimizing compilation, because they require data-flow information that is computed only when optimizing. If you don't specify `-O', you simply won't get these warnings.

If you try to compile with:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wuninitialized -O2 -o main *.c
```

The warning will be:

```
pippo.c: In function ‘main’:
pippo.c:56:5: warning: ‘y’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     printf("Hello, %d!\n", *x);
     ^
pippo.c:61:9: note: ‘y’ was declared here
     int y;
         ^
```

Comment: gcc 5.1.1 doesn't warn this. What version of gcc produces this warning?

Comment: @BlueMoon gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2

Comment: Hmm..I can't generate this warning even with (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2. You sure this warning was generated for OP's code?

Comment: @BlueMoon [HERE](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Better_Uninitialized_Warnings#Current_Situation) you could find a good analisys of -Wuninitialized flag

Comment: I added the [-O2 flag to my example](http://goo.gl/7ji931) and it produces the warning as described; this also uses 4.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Why should be something wrong in here ? you just passed that variable through that function which take as arg a Pointer. You did not passed its value, you passed its address with & so the compiler doesn't see this as a wrong, even if you later try to print its garbage value. Remember that you print at this point the value of the Pointer (*x) and not the variable itself.
Aren't variables initialized with a garbage value if you do not do it your self ?

But if you do not use a pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int const x)
{
    printf("Hello, %d!\n", x);
}

int main(void){
    int y;

    foo(y);
    y = 3;
    printf("Hello, World %d!\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

Things ar different now and compiler know about this:

> ```
>  program.c:12:5: error: ‘y’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
>      foo(y);
>      ^
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
> ```